# How to receive file by send on Android

Tags: android, android-intent, send

My manifest as below:

```
<activity android:name="SendLauncherActivity" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

I want to get each file's path.
So I have code as below:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String action = intent.getAction();
String type = intent.getType();

ArrayList<Uri> imageUris = intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
if (imageUris != null) {
    for(int i = 0; i < imageUris.size();i++) {
    System.out.println("Path " + imageUris.get(i).getPath());
    }
}
```

But I get path such as below:

```
01-17 18:21:13.350: I/System.out(20564): Path /external/file/15406
```

How can I modify to get the actual file path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might not be an "actual file path".

If you look, your scheme is probably `content://`. This is data served by a `ContentProvider`. There does not have to be a file.

You can use `ContentResolver` to get an `InputStream` for this `Uri`, regardless of whether it is a file or something else being streamed to you.